# Multiple YouTube players in activity

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I saw many posts about the issue that it is not possible to attach 2 or more Youtube players in one activity.
Its look like youtube api allows only 1 player per activity even if its on fragment.
There is a solution for it?

Comment: May I ask why one would want to play multiple videostreams simultaneously?

Comment: no there is not. If there was you won't have found so many posts telling you that is not possible.

Comment: @AndreasHartmann - I don't want to play multiple videos simultaneously. Just want scrollview with few player.

Comment: what you can do is to use the Thumbnail ImageView that comes with the sdk. When you start playing a video, store a reference to the current player. Before starting playing the second one, release it

Comment: @Blackbelt thanks. Good enough solution.